# How do I list the time stamp and commit message for git comits made this year?

Tags: git, git-log

I have a git history with multiple branches with some unmerged. I would like to extract a log of each comit forward from a single past comit to today.

I have had a look at Git Log but havent found a function which just gives me everything. I have just set a tag on the branch to set the starting point.

I would like the history to have the timestamp, comit message and branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --all --since="1 year ago" --author-date-order --pretty=format:'%at %s' > year.log
```

could be a base for what you need, to be tweaked if need be.

---

About the "branch" part : in short, you can't.

A bit more precisely, branches are mere pointers to track useful places in a repo tree, but they're ultimately disposable, while commits are *not*, they're the real matter of your history tree.

When a commit is made, many information enter its creation, but branches aren't part of that at all. What is relevant to git is the question "Is that commit *reachable* from this branch?".

By the way, you can commit with a detached HEAD state. If you do, what branch does this commit "belong" to? And if you go on commiting, and you later create a branch on the tip of your commit series, how could git retroactively write that branch information in now-immutable commits which are now "on" this branch?